# How can I create a transformation that maps a screen-space quad to a world-space plane?

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, directx

I'm trying to implement a screen-space ocean shader.

The basic gist of the approach is to draw a mesh in screen space, then "back project" it onto a plane in world space (in this case the XZ plane at 0 height, representing the sea surface).

Unfortunately, the paper doesn't go very much into how to generate a proper transformation from screen space back to world space, other than to use a frustrum based on the camera frustrum, a lot of plane/plane intersections, and a projection matrix that "looks visually pleasing." To compound issues, the method presented in the paper can't handle roll angles (only pitch and yaw).

So instead, I'd like to do the following approach: 
- Draw a screen space quad (or quad mesh, it doesn't matter) in 2D.
- Using some transformation, move that quad in screen space so it overlaps the view of the plane.
- When the camera has full view of the XZ plane (i.e. facing down), the quad shouldn't move and should occupy the whole screen.
- When the camera has no view of the XZ plane (i.e. facing up), the quad should be translated completely off the screen and be clipped.

In other words, I just want to draw a square and translate/rotate it so it covers the same pixels as the plane would if I drew the plane in world space.

So my question is this:

**Given a camera position, camera orientation quaternion, and view projection matrix, how can I translate and rotate a a 2D quad drawn in screen space so that it perfectly overlaps the XZ plane as seen from the camera?**

Obviously this approach takes a hit in that it's not efficient (half the time it's wasting polygon draws that are off-screen anyway), but at least it saves me a lot of complex code for testing plane-plane intersections and constant rebuilding of the screen-space mesh.

Comment: You forgot the viewport. You need that too, because screen-space coordinates are linearly mapped from NDC using the viewport and depth range. Now, the discussion is a little complicated by the fact that you included ***both*** OpenGL and D3D. D3D has a different NDC coordinate range (NDCz = [0,1] in D3D) than OpenGL, and a different origin in screen-space.

Comment: Well, I'm working in D3D. You're right that the viewport info is needed for OpenGL, but only the aspect ratio is needed in D3D.

Comment: Uhm, no. You still need to know the viewport in D3D. Without that, you cannot create screen-space coordinates from NDC. Or go from screen-space to NDC on your way back to world-space.

Comment: Why don't you just draw a plane in world space that is large enough? I don't see why the transformation to and from screen space is necessary. One big problem with screen space coordinates is correct perspective interpolation. It's impossible without introducing correct depth information. So why use screen space at all?